# Get Last character of String in angular

Tags: javascript, substring

Im trying to get the character after my string, I am using the bellow code but it dose not seem to work.

Input value: `fileinput-1`

Expected result: `1`

Any ideas. This is my code:

```
str = element.id;
str.substr(str.indexOf('-') + 1);
console.log(str);
index = str;
```

Comment: @Beep: Could you clear up if it is only the very last character you want, or if it's any character after the hyphen? For example, if your input was `fileinput-12`, what output would you expect?

Comment: your answer was perfect thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not doing anything with the result of the `substr` call. So the value of `str` is not being updated.

You need to assign the result back to `str`, like this:

```
str = str.substr(str.indexOf('-') + 1);
```

Comment: As string in JavaScript are immutable, we need to assign return value from  `substr` back to `str`.

Comment: The question  is `Get Last character of String in angular??` not get the all char's after the `-`.

Comment: @RameshRajendran: Is somebody in a grump? It wasn't me that downvoted your answer, even though I did comment... but I deleted the comment because I couldn't be bothered dealing with your reply

Comment: @Ram The title may say 'last character' but the question body says `"get the character after my string"`... also, the code suggests all characters after the hyphen. That means, 2 bits of information that indicate it should be characters after the hyphen, and only 1 bit of information it should be the last character. If you think all the way back to pre-school you will remember that 2 is greater than 1.... I appreciate that may have been a long time ago so I understand why you might be confused. Not to mention the OP accepted my answer

Answer (score 1):

substr() returns a string, you should catch it like this:

```
str = str.substr(str.indexOf('-') + 1 , 1);
```

or

```
var newstr = str.substr(str.indexOf('-') + 1, 1);
```

Comment: The question is `How to Get Last character of String in angular??`.  not get the all char's after the -.

Comment: @RameshRajendran you are right, I fixed it.

Comment: @RameshRajendran The question was changed. :-/

Answer (score 0):

try this with `substr()` or `slice()` one.

```js
var text = "field-1";
var result = text.substr(text.length - 1);
alert(result)
// or use slice
  var res= text.slice(-1); 
  alert(res)
```

Comment: Tempted to downvote because of ^^^^^^^ LOL (and missing semicolons) (and inconsistent indents) (and unnecessary second variable)